# Unexpected padding in tikz matrix with one row

Tags: matrices, tikz-matrix

When I produce a matrix in tikz in brackets, and then a row vector, I find the padding before the top row (with respect to the top of the brackets) is larger for the row vector than for the matrix. Is there a way to make this padding identical to that in the matrix?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (a) [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=[,right delimiter={]}] {
    2 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 2 \\
};
\matrix (b) [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=[,right delimiter={]},below=.5 of a] {
    0 & 0 & 2 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is due to the `inner ysep` of nodes. If you make them `0`, then the delimiters are of correct height but the horizontal space between rows will look ugly. This can be corrected by specifying a suitable `row sep` for the matrix. In the same manner the `inner xsep` can be made `0` too and `column sep` be adjusted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (a) [inner sep=1pt,matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=[,right delimiter={]},row sep=1.5ex,column sep=2ex] {
   2 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 2 \\
};
\matrix (b) [inner sep=1pt,matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=[,right delimiter={]},row sep=1.5ex,column sep=2ex,below=.5 of a] {
    0 & 0 & 2 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I suggest to use `bmatrix` from `amsmath` for this job, if it is allowed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) [inner sep=0pt] {
   $\begin{bmatrix}
       2 & 1 & 0 \\
       0 & 1 & 2
   \end{bmatrix}$
};
\node (b) [inner sep=0pt,below=.5 of a] {
    $\begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 & 2
    \end{bmatrix}$
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]